# Can PCs really swap ANY skill at a Minor Milestone?

Tags: fate, fate-core, character-advancement

I am reading the "The Long Game" chapter of the Fate Core System book and one thing is not totally clear to me.  On page 256, when - speaking about minor milestones it is said:

> Switch the rank values of any two skills, or replace one Average (+1)
>   skill with one that isn’t on your sheet.

Here, "any two skills" seem to indicate that it is possible to swap really *any* two skills on the character sheet, even a *Legendary* for an *Average*.  However the second part of the sentence (*Average* vs. *Nothing*) would then seem inconsistent, by limiting the swap between "adjacent levels" in the pyramid.  The example that follows do not resolve this ambiguity as they are about swapping *Good* and *Fair*, also levels of the pyramid that are one on top of the other.

Furthermore, from a narrative standpoint, I would argue that this being a *minor* milestone, it makes little sense for somebody who was a thug (*Great* fight, *Average* lore) to suddenly become Einstein (*Great* lore, *Average* fight).

**Should I interpret "any two skills" as "any two skills on adjacent rows"?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Any means any, but Fate Core includes some suggestions.

> This is a good way to make slight character adjustments, if it seems like something on your character isn’t quite right […] or any of those
>   changes that keep your character consistent with the events of play.
>
> ---
>
> In fact, you should almost always be able to justify the change you’re
>   making in terms of the game’s story. […] GMs, you’re the final arbiter on this, but don’t be so much of a stickler that you sacrifice a player’s fun for consistency.